# How to improve search results with QueryElevationComponent?

Tags: performance, solr

I'm using solr 1.4 and using QueryElevation Component for guaranteed search position. I have around 700,000 documents with 1 Mb elevation file. It turns out it is quite slow on the newrelic monitoring website:

```
Slowest Components                                       Count   Exclusive           Total    
QueryElevationComponent                                1    506,858 ms 100% 506,858 ms 100%
SolrIndexSearcher                                        1    2.0 ms    0%    2.0 ms    0%
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter()    1    1.0 ms    0%    506,862 ms 100%
QueryComponent                                            1    1.0 ms    0%   1.0 ms    0%
DebugComponent                                            1    0.0 ms    0%    0.0 ms    0%
FacetComponent                                            1    0.0 ms    0%    0.0 ms    0%
```

I'm looking for how to improve the speed of the search query. The
QueryElevation Component is taking too much time which is
unacceptable. The size of elevation file is only 1 Mb. I wonder other
people using this component without problems (related to speed)? Am I
using it the wrong way or there is a limit when using this component?

Comment: 1 Mb? How many documents do you boost?

Comment: Around 10,500 documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a huge number of docs you want to elevate - I'm sure this wasn't designed for that :-)!

Isn't there a common attribute of your docs e.g. salesrank, where you can then simply use the dismax handler to boost the docs? e.g. via `bf=recip(sqrt(sales_rank_i),1,1,1))`

(Or you could simply sort the docs against this salesrank field)

Or couldn't you introduce such a field?

Comment: what does this function (recip) mean? What's about other values (1,1,1)? What is salesrank used for?

Comment: you should add a new field 'sales rank' to every doc. and if you want to boost a doc give it a lower sales_rank (the lower the better). recip means reziprocal something like 1/(m*x+1). for this look here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: Using that recip function query, how do we guarantee search position? I must be able to control the search result position of each search query.

Comment: do you mean guarantee position of documents for different queries? why would you then need a search engine if the returned position is always the same? (sorry if these are stupid I'm not familiar with the elevation component that much). Maybe you can ask on the mailing list too. the order can be guaranteed if you sort against sales_rank, yes. and all documents without this field will come after them if you set sortMissingLast="true" for that field

Comment: The search results is not the same. The logic is if they buy a keyphrase with a specific position, they'll be on that position if the user search for that keyphrase.

Comment: ah, ok. this is your usecase. try asking on the mailing list again