# How can I elevate the top 10,000 records using elevate.xml in Solr?

Tags: solr

I have 100,000 records. I need to elevate the top 10,000 records using `elevate.xml`. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to elevate *10000* documents? It seems like a lot, maybe there's an alternative, better way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Yes. There are also other ways to perform this task like boosting. I think this is possible by customizing QueryElevateComponent. Check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1147 and share your idea.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent), the QueryElevationComponent is used to configure the top results for specific queries. I may be wrong, but I would guess that you want to give a higher weight to your 10,000 records irrespective of the query. You could use index time boosts as explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts). Alternately, you could add a field with some special value (like `boost:true`) to these special records and use a boost query (`bq`) as explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29).

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'm thinking about customizing Query Elevation Component file.Check this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1147. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see the relation between SOLR-1147 and your question. SOLR-1147 can be used to change elevate.xml but we are trying to figure out how to use elevate.xml for 10000 records. Maybe you could provide some more details including a sample use case so that I can try to provide a specific solution.

Comment: I'm having 10000 records under the collection 'companies'.CompanyA is having 3000 records,B 4000 records,C 3000 records.4000 records of B should come first,then C and at last A.On using elevate.xml,I should enter unique id of 10000 records in the order B,C,A.Instead of that,Why don't I execute query like "select/?q=B" which will return all 4000 records,then q=C and q=A i.e Instead of uniquefield,execute query in an order.   
Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to write a query instead of ids in elevate.xml.  BTW, do you want to always return the 4k records of company B at the top irrespective of what the query is, or do you want to return only those records of company B which match the query?

Comment: return only records of company B which match the query.Are you sure that there is no way for passing 'http request' as a parameter in elevate.xml?

Comment: Even if there was, how do you plan to use it?  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057464/how-to-improve-search-results-with-queryelevationcomponent) for the performance impact. Also, I believe that QueryElevationComponent boosts the specified records irrespective of whether they match the query or not - so if you supply all the 4k records of company B to QueryElevationComponent, then they will all be returned irrespective of whether they match the query or not.

Comment: Its working..I just made some changes in QueryElvationComponent java file and created a new jar.Now it is not necessary that i have to mention all the uniquefield of 10000 records.Just mention <doc id=CompanyB/> <doc id=CompanyC/><doc id=CompanyA/> in elevate.xml

Answer (score -1):

This is possible after customizing the QueryElevationComponent java file.Its working now!!!

Comment: Can you share your customizations as part of the answer?